# Firebird C client API: statement, transaction and cursor lifecycle

Tags: c++, firebird

Context: Firebird 2.5, C client API.

I would like to understand the lifecycle of statement, transaction and cursor objects. Here is what I do (pseudo-code):

```
class Query {
  isc_tr_handle _transaction;
  isc_stmt_handle _statement;
  XSQLDA* _in_sqlda;
  XSQLDA* _out_sqlda;

  void prepare(){ 
      isc_dsql_allocate_statement(...,&_statement,...); 
      isc_dsql_prepare(&_transaction, &_statement);
  }

  void execute(Input* input, Output* output) {
     ... copy input to _in_sqlda

     isc_dsql_set_cursor_name(status, &_statement, Name(), NULL);

     isc_dsql_execute(status, &_transaction, &_statement, 1, in_sqlda);

     while(fetch()) {
        ... copy _out_sqlda to output
     }   

     isc_dsql_free_statement(status, &_statement, DSQL_close);      

  }

  void commit() { isc_commit_transaction(status, &_transaction); }
};
```

The call to `isc_dsql_free_statement` is only to close the cursor? The `statement` remains valid and I can call again and again execute with different input?

Comment: Your question is too broad, please stick to **one** question per question. I strongly suggest you edit this question so it is about only one thing, and post additional questions for the other two. If subjects are related, then you can link between questions.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to remove the other two questions from your post. Please post separate questions for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `isc_dsql_free_statement` does depends on the third parameter. There are three valid values (see also the Interbase 6.0 API Guide and the Firebird 2.5 release notes):

1. `DSQL_close`: closes open cursor (if any), but leaves the current statement prepared and the handle remains valid.
2. `DSQL_drop`: closes open cursor (if any), unprepares the current statement and drops the statement handle.
3. [`DSQL_unprepare`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes255.html#rnfb25-apiods-api-unprpr) (added in Firebird 2.5): closes open cursor (if any), unprepares the current statement, but the handle itself remains valid.

In your code you use `isc_dsql_free_statement(status, &_statement, DSQL_close);` which means the cursor is closed (if any), the current statement remains prepared and can be executed again (or you can prepare another statement on this handle).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually read again the Interbase API guide and found out about DSQL_drop. As for DSQL_unprepare, what would be the use case ?

Comment: @SoyonsPrecis It unprepares the statement, releasing any locks held on metadata objects (which would otherwise block certain DDL actions), but leaves the handle valid for reuse (eg for a pool of statement handles or something like that). I think it is really an edge case.